# how to get distance in meter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, geography

i have below store procedure i want to check distance of my car latitude longitude which geofence nearest if distance in meter less then 500 show geofence id which geofence id nearest car latitude longitude.if car latitude longitude nearest  polygon show polygon ID and if rectangle show rectangle id i am new in sql server that's why i am here please help me professionals i am very thankful to you, demo table are in shared link,

[question and demo table is here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxP2jDqb5_3pb0o5UnBjUjZJUm8?usp=sharing)

```
CREATE TABLE CarDistance 
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
car_id int,
latitude float,
longitude float

)
insert into CarDistance values(1234, '52.582191','-2.878418')

CREATE TABLE tblgeofencing2  
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
car_id int,
ShapeType  varchar(255),
PolygonLatLng  varchar(max),
minlatitude [float] NULL,
    [minlongitude] [float] NULL,
    [maxlatitude] [float] NULL,
    [maxlongitude] [float] NULL,
)

insert into tblgeofencing2 values(123, 'polygon','24.835300590037598 67.06858277320862,24.835933468801272 67.06929624080658,24.83532979989791 67.07035303115845,24.83454113125045 67.0697683095932,24.835300590037598 67.06858277320862',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into tblgeofencing2 values(1234, 'rectangle','NULL','52.582191','-2.878418','52.233687','-2.702637')

Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_CheckCarStatusMeter]  
 DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY, 
         @ID INT,
     @curVal     INT, 
         @preVal     INT ,  
     @CarSuggested INT,  
     @carlatprevious VARCHAR(10), 
         @carlongprevious VARCHAR(10), 
    @AllLatitudeLongitude VARCHAR(255),     
         @pprevious GEOGRAPHY

 DECLARE SuggestCursor CURSOR  FOR
       SELECT TOP 100 rtha.car_id , rtha.latitude,  
           rtha.longitude 
     FROM   CarDistance rtha WHERE rtha.car_id = 123;
     OPEN SuggestCursor;  
     FETCH NEXT FROM SuggestCursor INTO @CarSuggestedID , @carlatprevious , @carlongprevious; 

     WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)    
 BEGIN       

     DECLARE ShapeCursor CURSOR FOR  
  SELECT g.ID, @CarSuggestedID,  g.ShapeType  FROM   tblgeofencing AS g
         WHERE  car_id =@CarSuggestedID 
  FETCH NEXT FROM ShapeCursor INTO @ID , @CarIdx , @ShapeType; 

     WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
     BEGIN 
     IF (@ShapeType = 'polygon')
         BEGIN --Polygon IF 
             PRINT 'polygon if'; 
             SELECT @GeofenceIDnew = g.GeoFenceId,  @minY = g.PolygonLatLng ROM   tblgeofencing AS g
             WHERE  g.ID = =@CarSuggestedID 
             SET @g = geography ::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((' + @AllLatitudeLongitude + '))', 4326);           
             SET @pprevious = geography ::STPointFromText(
                     'POINT(' + @carlatprevious + ' ' + @carlongprevious +  ')',  4326   ); 
             SELECT @preVal = @g.STIntersects(@pprevious) 
             PRINT @preVal  
             IF @curVal = 1 AND @preVal = 0 
             BEGIN  
                PRINT 'Enter In GEOFENCE';  
                 SELECT @geofencename = geofenceName, 
                        @geofenceidforresult = ID  
                 FROM   tblgeofencing where ID = @CarSuggestedID;
                 INSERT INTO tblGeofenceCarStatus  
                 VALUES 
                   ( 
                     @CarSuggestedID,  @geofenceidforresult,@geofencename,  
                     @gpstime, @g.STDistance(@pprevious), 'Enter' ); 

             END  
        ELSE
BEGIN
Print Not in Geofence
END

         END; --- END POLYGON IF 
   FETCH NEXT FROM ShapeCursor INTO @ID , @CarIdx , @ShapeType;  



     END; --- END CHECK GEOFENCING RECTANGLE OR CIRCLE OR PLYGON 


      FETCH NEXT FROM SuggestCursor INTO @CarSuggestedID , @carlatprevious , @carlongprevious;  



       END;
     CLOSE ShapeCursor;  
      DEALLOCATE ShapeCursor;  
        CLOSE SuggestCursor;
       DEALLOCATE SuggestCursor; 
     SELECT * FROM   tblGeofenceCarStatus;    

 END;  

END; --- END SP BEGIN  STATEMENT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution will:

- identify the most recent position of each car
- identify the previous position of each car
- construct geofence polygons based on polygon string or rectangle coordinates
- identify cars that are currently within 500 metres of a geo-fence (from the outside) OR are inside a geo-fence
- show distance from geo-fence as at previous position

```sql
;
WITH car_location_seq AS (
        SELECT   car_id
                ,ID
                ,latitude
                ,longitude
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Pos_Sequence
        FROM #CarDistance
),
car_location AS (
        SELECT   c1.car_id
                ,geography::Point(c1.longitude, c1.latitude,  4326) AS Geo_Point_Current
                ,CASE WHEN c2.car_id IS NOT NULL THEN geography::Point(c2.longitude, c2.latitude,  4326) END AS Geo_Point_Previous
        FROM car_location_seq c1 -- Most recent position
            LEFT JOIN car_location_seq c2 -- Previous position
                ON c1.car_id = c2.car_id
                AND c2.Pos_Sequence = 2
        WHERE c1.Pos_Sequence = 1
),
fences AS (
        SELECT   ID
                ,Car_ID
                ,CASE   WHEN ShapeType = 'polygon' THEN geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((' + PolygonLatLng + '))', 4326)
                        WHEN ShapeType = 'rectangle' THEN geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((' + 
                                CAST(maxlatitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + CAST(minlongitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ', ' + 
                                CAST(minlatitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + CAST(minlongitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ', ' + 
                                CAST(minlatitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + CAST(maxlongitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ', ' + 
                                CAST(maxlatitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + CAST(maxlongitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ', ' + 
                                CAST(maxlatitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + CAST(minlongitude AS VARCHAR(100)) + 
                                '))', 4326)
                END AS Geo_Polygon
        FROM #tblgeofencing2
)

SELECT   f.ID AS Fence_ID
        ,c.car_id
        ,c.Geo_Point_Current
        --,c.Geo_Point_Current.STAsText()
        ,f.Geo_Polygon
        --,f.Geo_Polygon.STAsText()
        ,f.Geo_Polygon.STIntersects(c.Geo_Point_Current) AS Is_Inside_Fence_Current
        ,f.Geo_Polygon.STIntersects(c.Geo_Point_Previous) AS Is_Inside_Fence_Previous
        ,f.Geo_Polygon.STDistance(c.Geo_Point_Current) AS Distance_Current
        ,f.Geo_Polygon.STDistance(c.Geo_Point_Previous) AS Distance_Previous
--INTO #Relevant_Car_Positions
FROM fences f
    INNER JOIN car_location c
        ON f.car_id = c.car_id

WHERE f.Geo_Polygon.STDistance(c.Geo_Point_Current) < 500
;
```

Sample output:

[image: Sample query result]

You should be able to adapt this code to suit your needs. For example, you could first store the query output into a temporary table by uncommenting `INTO #Relevant_Car_Positions`.